# exc_bad_access when Property added

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a TabBarController in one tab I have a TableViewController inside a NavigationController.
When I add a property like

```
@property CGFloat rowHeight;
```

or add something like

```
if ([self.modelTypeCell isEqualToString:@"TypeOneCell"])
```

I get an

```
error: gdb remote returned an error: E08 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1....
```

in this line

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

I cant debug anything and no breakpoint get hit before the error occurs.

EDIT: Zombies didnt give me informations, in Instruments and on a real device no error was thrown...

EDIT2:
I found out the problem should lay here

```
-(void)setupControllerDictionaries
{
self.masterViewControllerDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

TableMasterViewController *master = [[TableMasterViewController alloc] initWithModelType:ModelTypeCustomer];

[self.masterViewControllerDictionary setObject:master forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ModelTypeCustomer]];
[master release];
```

}

when I comment out the master release the error is gone, maybe its the error maybe its somewhere else

Comment: Enable zombies and a breakpoint on all exceptions, because this is the least specific error message of them all.

Comment: Add an [Exception Breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW18)

Comment: I did it but nothing changed, no more informations. I figured out when i comment out the line where I make the nsarray for the controllers the error is gone but don't know why.

Comment: The error occurs just by adding the property declaration? And commenting it out resolves the error? Really? That I can hardly believe... The error is somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, I will edit my question now I have new informations.

Answer (score 2):

Property can be best used when written like this:

@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat rowHeight;

nonatomics is for that the property can perform in multiple threads and assign means that property should use assignment property while assigning to property something. The retain can not be used with this as this variable is not a pointer type

Comment: Just an add to your answer: if you want to use the notation "self.property" you have to do a "@synthesize property"

Comment: The if statement does the same error, I remove all release from my appdelegate but its the same but only in simulator without instruments...

Comment: Note that (Atomic, assign) would work just as well (even faster), and that it is the default.

Comment: @MarcoPace synthesize is no longer neccessary in newest xCode versions. codaFi atomic is not a keyword (at least last time I checked ;) and nonatomic would be actually faster than atomic

Comment: @CodaFi I believe the truth is just the opposite.  Atomic incurs overhead and that is why the vast majority of programmers use non atomic explicitly.

Comment: @borrrden you're right.  But nonatomicity makes no promises about whole return values, where atomicity makes a guarantee of a whole value being returned, even in the case of access by multiple threads.